# Inherit R function argument from global variable

Tags: r, function, arguments

I am trying to create a function where the default argument is given by a variable that only exists in the environment temporarily, e.g.:

```
arg=1:10
test=function(x=arg[3]){2*x}

> test()
[1] 6
```

The above works fine, as long as arg exists in the function environment. However, if I remove arg:

```
> rm(arg)
> test()
> Error in test() : object 'arg' not found
```

Is there a way such that the default argument is taken as 3, even when arg ceases to exist? I have a feeling the correct answer involves some mixture of eval, quote and/or substitute, but I can't seem to find the correct incantation.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You could change `test`'s `environment` and assign `arg` in there -- `environment(test) = new.env(); environment(test)$arg = 1:10` if you want to remove `arg` from the global environment.

Comment: There are a few routes that would achieve similar behaviour, but I guess I'm just keen to know if the value of the argument can be evaluated statically. At the extreme I could clearly write everything out as a script (with the 3rd element of arg evaluated explicitly as 3 and set as the default for x) and source this. Is there a way to achieve this entirely within the R environment?

Comment: You could `eval` the arguments and re-assign them using `"formals<-"` -- e.g. `formals(test)$x = eval(formals(test)$x)`. You could, also, make an intermediate function that evaluates its arguments and returns a function with the valuated arguments.

Comment: Thanks- that got me on the right track. I've posted my solution at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it in my opinion would be:

```
test <- function(x=3) { 2 *x }
```

and then call it with an argument:

```
arg<-1:10
test(arg[3])
```

This way the default value is 3, then you pass it the argument you wish at runtime, if you call it without argument `test()` it will use the default.

Answer (score 1):

The post above got me on the right track. Using formals:

```
arg=1:10
test=function(x){x*2}
formals(test)$x=eval(arg[3])
rm(arg)
test()
```

[1] 6

And that is what I was looking to achieve.